# There is brownish water coming out of hot water tap

Tags: water-heater

Brown water out of hot h2o tap.  Anode rod in water tank completely gone.  Will new rod stop the brown h2o or is the tank corroded beyond saving.  Tank is 8yrs

Comment: Start saving for a new tank.  A new rod will probably extend the time, but depends on how long the rod has been gone.  Turn off the heater and the water when not watching it.

Comment: Thanks "crip659".   My thoughts too.

Comment: It's possible the brown is coming from corroded steel piping, if you have any of that old stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Unable to determine the condition of your tank, but given the age of your tank and that the anode rod is entirely gone, you are on borrowed time (especially if the anode rod was never previously replaced).

You should be looking at getting a new tank.

Comment: Thanks for the input "pdd".   Believe you right.